# In Repository, a filter function returns dynamic vector or another Repository

Tags: c++, oop, repository

I am currently learning the OOP paradigm in C++ (my program must have a class for an object - ex: TrenchCoat, Repository- list of trench coats, Controller and User Interface). I must make a method in the Repository class that returns the trench coats with a given size. I have 2 choices:

1) I return an STL vector with the wanted objects
ex: std::vector filterBySize(int size);

2) In the method, I create another Repository and the wanted objects I add to this second Repository and return the Repository.
ex: Repository filterBySize(int size);

I don't know which choice is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, there is not a correct answer, the better solution depends on what do you want to do after the filter operation.
Returning a Repository objects, it makes easier  further and different operations (for example another filtering by color). In fact, supposing that another method `Repository filterbyColor(String color)`  exists in the Repository class, it could be called directly from the previous filter operation, as below:

```
 Repository filteredRepo=repo.filterBySize(40).filterByColor('yellow');
```

Instead, if you don't need to perform further operations, you can simply return a vector.